# how to get propertygrid items name, lable and value in c#?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I define item in propertygrid. My code is here :

```
[DisplayName("Title of book"), CategoryAttribute("Books")]
public string BookName{ get; set; }
```

With this code , I can get Labele and value of this item from propertygrid(for this example : *Title of book* and value of it (for example) *Learning C#*):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridItem gi = propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem;
    while (gi.Parent != null)
    {
        gi = gi.Parent;
    }
    foreach (GridItem item in gi.GridItems)
    {
        ParseGridItems(item); //recursive
    }
}

private void ParseGridItems(GridItem gi)
{
    if (gi.GridItemType == GridItemType.Category)
    {
        foreach (GridItem item in gi.GridItems)
        {
            ParseGridItems(item);
        }
    }
    textBox1.Text += "Lable : "+gi.Label + "\r\n";
    if(gi.Value != null)
        textBox1.Text += "Value : " + gi.Value.ToString() + "\r\n";
}
```

How can I get the item name ? for this example : *BookName*

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Comment: I use propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myclass; for set my class to propertygrid items. How can I access to values and names of visual propertygrid items ,No my class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GridItem.PropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.griditem.propertydescriptor.aspx) property:

```
var propertyName = propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks, gi.PropertyDescriptor.Name + " : " + gi.Value.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the entries if you inherit the PropertyGrid control. In the inherrited class, put this new property:

```
public GridItem[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                System.Reflection.FieldInfo field_gridView = typeof(PropertyGrid).GetField("gridView", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

                object gridView = field_gridView.GetValue(this);

                System.Reflection.MethodInfo gridView_method_GetAllGridEntries = gridView.GetType().GetMethod("GetAllGridEntries", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null);

                object gridEntries_collection = gridView_method_GetAllGridEntries.Invoke(gridView, new object[0]);

                System.Reflection.MethodInfo gridEntries_collection_count_method = gridEntries_collection.GetType().GetMethod("get_Count");

                int count_entries = (int) gridEntries_collection_count_method.Invoke(gridEntries_collection, new object[0]);

                System.Reflection.MethodInfo gridEntries_collection_getItem_method = gridEntries_collection.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item", new Type[] { typeof(int) });

                GridItem[] entries = new GridItem[count_entries];

                for (int i = 0; i < count_entries; i++)
                {
                    entries[i] = gridEntries_collection_getItem_method.Invoke(gridEntries_collection, new object[] { i }) as GridItem;
                }

                return entries;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps,
Anben.